# gnome-terminal "cannot open location" error

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu. But after taking a lot of time and pain..I installed Ubuntu Server edition onto my server, got the GUI installed.

Now when I press Alt+F2, I get the "run application" window.
But when ever I enter gnome-terminal it gives me this error message "could not open location file:///home/username/gnome-terminal"

I dont know why it is giving this. Can anyone help me with this??

thanks in advance.

Comment: This should go to http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Try xterm, that opens a terminal window. No clue for gnome-terminal though.

Comment: @yash On Ubuntu desktop edition, gnome-terminal should be installed by default.   I suspect the problem is the way you've converted server to support GUI apps.   Can you tell us what steps you took (even approximately) to get GUI support?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 0):

That's strange.
With debian, it works fine… Did you try to give the full path to the gnome-terminal executable (i.e. /usr/bin/gnome-terminal)?
If it doesn't work, Alt+F2 call seems to be broken.

Comment: I don't have the Gnome version installed to verify, but I can imagine this happening if `gnome-terminal` isn't installed or in `$PATH`:  first it does a `PATH` search, then falls back to trying the current directory, then reports the error based on that last attempt.

Comment: Try whereis: `renaud@daneel:~$ whereis gnome-terminal` and if you get `gnome-terminal: ` with nothing after then gnome-terminal is definitely not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Gnome-Do](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Main_Page) instead of the Alt-F2.  It's much more powerful.